# Локализация array plist в Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Столкнулся с токой проблемой, когда делаю локализацию к Players.plist (массив), то у меня перестает правильно работать. (отображаются старые значения, которые были в players.plist до локализации). (подгружаю через создания патча к файлу - NSBundle, а дальше свойства массивИзКонтекстФайла, думаю понятно).

До локализации, players.plist лежал прямо в папке моего приложения, после локализации он автоматически был удален и теперь два файла players.plist лежат соответственно в русской и английской папке локализаций (это я говорю, чтобы не думали что у меня оставлся старый файл и с него идет чтение).

Конечно мне удалось создать несколько не связанных между собой файлов и в зависимости от значения `[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0]` подгружать нужный файл.

Но почему это не делается автоматически??!!!!!

Comment: xcode 4.6 у меня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, ваш вопрос состоит из двух частей:

1. Старый файл остался где-то в кэше и подгружается несмотря на изменившуюся в связи с локализацией структуру проекта.
2. Заработает ли ваш код использующий `NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Players.plist" ofType:NULL];`

Для начала нужно что-то попробовать по поводу первого вопроса:

Вы в курсе, что `Xcode` разворачивает приложения, которые вы запускаете в симуляторе, в папке

```
/Users/Ваше имя/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1 (6.1 это версия iOS)
```

?

Это грубый способ, но он может по крайней мере что-то прояснить: удалить в соответствующей папке директорию (много букв и цифр) вашего проекта - при следующей загрузке `Xcode` должен будет пересобрать `bundle` заново.

Comment: Я уже делал Сбросить Контент и Настройки (так что по идее все должно было очиститься). Ладно не буду заморачивать голову, буду грузить файлы в зависимости от [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0] . Так что этот вопрос я удаляю

Comment: Я бы всё-таки советовал проверить именно ручное удаление, а потом уже сделать окончатеьный вывод.

Comment: мне почемуто даже не удается найти папку Библеотека в Mac(Mac- это название моего макбук). Я всего месяц сижу на маке (купил специально для ios development).

Comment: Да, тут понадобится использовать мышление: http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/productivity/how-to-reveal-your-library-folder-in-lion-or-mountain-lion/

Comment: Я уже реализую через класс NSUserDefaults, так что не хочу вас обижать, но наверное уже тема не актуальна. Только я не вижу ссылку на Удалить вопрос

Comment: Хотя проще всего это сделать через консоль, используя просто __cd ~/Library__

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Мне удалось в консоли перейти в эту папку, но как дальше отобразить содержимое в папке я не знаю (с мак ос очень слабо знаком, а в cmd в винде работал). Но сейчас я реализую уже через NSUserDefaults, так что спасибо, но я удалил бы вопрос если знал как

Comment: Нужно внизу вопроса нажать "Тревога" и указать причину: вы хотите удалить вопрос, потому что...